# Antiderivative of a polynomial fraction

Tags: calculus, integration, polynomials

I am trying to solve this problem and I can't seem to understand where I am going wrong. My understanding of antiderivatives is this formula:
$$
\int x^{n} \mathrm{d}x = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+c
$$
The problem I am trying to solve is:

$$f(x)=\frac{x^5-x^3+8x}{x^4}$$

I think there are two possible parts that I am getting wrong, I started the problem by separating them into individual fractions and solving each fraction at a time. I think I get it wrong at either the $\ln(x)$ or $\frac{8x^{-2}}{-2}$. Here is my attempt:

$$f(x)= \frac{x^5}{x^4}-\frac{x^3}{x^4}+\frac{8x}{x^4}
        = x-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{8}{x^3}$$

Then from here I get the antiderivative:

$$F(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}-\ln(x)+\frac{8x^{-2}}{-2}+c
        =\frac{x^2}{2}-\ln(x)-\frac{4}{x^2}+c$$

I keep getting the wrong answer when I plug it in, am I missing some fundamental piece of information about antiderivatives which is causing me to mess up the $\ln(x)$ or is my algebra wrong and I mess up around $\frac{8x^{-2}}{-2}$?

Comment: Weird, I tried to edit to format your math so I could read it better, but it wouldn't modify the appearance like usual.  How did you get the gray boxes, cut and paste?

Comment: Maybe it was because I was trying to edit it too? No, no copy and paste, when you are editing or posting something the gray boxes appear when you hit the {} or use " ` " characters.

Comment: The first term should be $\frac{x^2}2$, not $\frac{x^2}x$.

Comment: That was a typo, my bad.

Comment: What does “getting the wrong answer when I plug it in” mean? “Plug it in” where?

Comment: When I plug it into my grader. It says it is wrong, I am trying to figure out where I went wrong.

Comment: You have to write $\ln(| x |)$.

Comment: You are right. I needed the absolute value. Is there a reason for this? Does ln not accept a negative number? I may have heard that somewhere but I am unsure.

Comment: Can you post that answer with an explanation, please?

Comment: Because $\ln x$ is only defined for positive $x$, but your function has an antiderivative for both $x\gt 0$ and $x\lt 0$. You need to account for both possibilities. That’s why the most general antiderivative of $\frac{1}{x}$ is $\ln|x|+C$, and not $\ln(x)+C$ or $\ln(-x)+C$; the latter are only valid for *part* of the domain, not the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain of the natural logarithm is $(0,\infty)$.  However, $1/x$ is defined on $(-\infty, 0) \cup (0, \infty)$, so should be the derivative of some function defined on this larger set.  That "some function" is $\ln|x|$.  That is
$$  \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \ln|x| = \frac{1}{x}, \quad x \neq 0  $$
so
$$  \ln |x| + C = \int \frac{1}{x} \,\mathrm{d}x  , \quad x \neq 0  \text{.}  $$

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to research why domain of $ln(x)$ is $(0,\infty)$. But this solved my question at least. I am just trying to wrap my head around the idea of this. I understand why x cannot be 0 but not my $ln(x)$ must be positive x.

Comment: @xtryingx : The natural logarithm is the inverse function of the exponential.  Since $\mathrm{e}^x > 0$ for all $x$, the natural logarithm, $\ln x$, is only defined for $x > 0$.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks. I looked at a graph and it helped too.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the integration of $x$:

$$\int x-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{8}{x^3}\,dx=\frac{x^2}{2}-\ln \mid x\mid - \frac{4}{x^2} +C$$

Comment: I think I see it, I am messing up on the $\frac{8}{x^3} aren't I?

Comment: no, I thought that you've integrated $$\int x \,dx$$ as $$\frac{x^2}{x}$$ but this is was a typo as you said in the comment so there is no mistake in your answer, but you must know that the natural log is not defined for values $\le 0$ @xtryingx